# Calculate jquery height of prev() and add or subtract it to current

Tags: jquery, dynamic, height, slide

I have a css class called myDiv which slides down when a thumbnail image is clicked:

```
#myDiv
{
  height:800px;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:100%:
}
```

When a user clicks on a thumbnail image, the `myDiv` will appear 800px tall. Because there are multiple thumbnail images with varying height for `myDiv` e.g. clicking thumbnail 1 will make `myDiv` 700px tall and thumbnail 2 200px tall, is there a way to calculate the height dynamically using jQuery?

As I am not proficient in this language I can only describe the scenario, so here goes...

jQuery: 
1. Click 1: When thumbnail 1 is clicked, get height of `myDiv` class = 700px and slide down
2. Click 2: When thumbnail 2 is clicked, get height of previous class (700px) and current class (200px) and subtract from each other to determine the slide up or down value (700px - 200px = 500px).

Is there a way to calculate the previous and current height of `myDiv` so that it slides up or down to the corresponding height?

Your help is very much appreciated.

EDIT: CSS and jQuery

```
#box
{
max-width:1140px;
margin: 0 auto;
display: inline-block;

}

html[xmlns] #portfoliocontainer {
display: block;
}

* html #portfoliocontainer {
height: 1%;
}

#portfoliocontainer:after {
clear: both;
content: ".";
display: block;
height: 0;
line-height: 0;
visibility: hidden;
}
```

And the jQuery is:

```
$('#box').hide();
$('#myDiv').hide();
$('.portfolio-area').click(function(){
$('#myDiv').hide();

$('#box').slideDown('slow');
$('#myDiv').fadeTo('slow',1);

});
```

Comment: did you just want myDiv to slide down with dynamic height?

Comment: Hi Huangism, yep that's right. The content being displayed within myDiv has varying height. I understand that jQuery has a bug with using min-height whilst animating the slide up or down. I just want the myDiv to fit the height of the content being displayed.

Comment: I think that the easiest way to do it would be to get the previous height and current of myDiv and subtract it to get the slide up or down value in pixels for a smooth animation.

Comment: how are you changing the content? can you give a simple example on fiddle? I am thinking if your content changes then you shouldn't need to define a set height for it to animate, it should be auto height so it will slide down to as far as the content has filled it

Comment: I have uploaded my latest example on my site: http://circularchaos.com/jq/. The content is changed dynamically using AJAX. I need to set a height because there is other content sitting underneath the myDiv. So when myDiv opens content underneath is pushed down. Currently the height of myDiv is set to 850px. When you click on a thumbnail you can see that the myDiv has a fixed height so even if the content is small there will still be whitespace underneath. I've tried setting the height to auto but the slide animation breaks and the myDiv overlaps the content underneath - Thanks

Comment: the other content "hi" right? you want that to be after the portfolio content correct? and right now it is getting attached to the end of your list-items. I honestly think you can just strip the height and clear fix the other content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is a clearfix. You can clearfix #portfolio div conainer and remove the defined height, then all is well

http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html

The li's inside of the portfolio div are floating so that div is not getting any height which clearfix will fix, then the height will be dynamic without defining it.

For a simple test add this and remove the adding height part

```
#portfoliocontainer:after {
    clear: both;
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

You should create the clearfix class and add it to that id

Comment: Thank you Huangism for that. Your solution did fix the problem of the height issue by using clearfix. The content fits within the 'myDiv'. But now my slider is overlapping the thumbnails underneath and the jQuery slide animation is 'jumping'. The myDiv is the hidden div that is displayed when you click on a thumbnail. The 'hi' content was just another separate test. Is there another way to pre-calculate a div's height before displaying it? Because it has to be dynamic I will need the height of the previous div as well. I think thats the main issue - Thanks!

Comment: is the clearfix update on the site now? I need to see this so I understand the problem

Comment: @Raja Actually, remove the height setting, first of all. After the ajax has filled the content correctly, get the height of the ul.portfolio-area then set the height so it is the new height. Create a clone page for testing

Comment: The update is live now. Sorry I'll update every change from now on. Also the name of the hidden div is actually #box and not #myDiv :) As you can see the height of the div only includes up to the text and ignores the slideshow.

Comment: there is still that set height on the ul doesn't matter how many icons are showing, can you post the js where it sets the height?

Comment: The height was set through CSS and I have removed the hight value from #box. All the jQuery does is control the sliding animation. I have edited the original post to include these changes for CSS and jQuery. The thumbnails are fine its just the #box div.

Comment: Hi Huangaism, I have marked your answer as accepted because in effect it did answer my question about displaying content using dynamic height. I am just going to work on the jQuery side of things for the animation. Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: if you run into more problems, you can post another question, but be specific and post related code

Comment: Sure thing Huangism! Thanks :)